# How do I add text before the share social buttons title?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add some text before the title. For example, " New - the_title() "

```
$crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());
```

So it will show up like, "New - Planet tee "

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_share', 'crunchify_social_sharing_buttons');
function crunchify_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
    if(is_singular() || is_home()){

        // Get current page URL 
        $crunchifyURL = get_permalink();

        // Get current page title
        $crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

        // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
        $crunchifyThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

        // Construct sharing URL without using any script
        $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$crunchifyTitle.'&amp;url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
        $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$crunchifyURL;

        // Based on popular demand added Pinterest too
        $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;media='.$crunchifyThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
        $content .= '<div class="crunchify-social">';
        $content .= '<h5>SHARE ON</h5> <a class="crunchify-link crunchify-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank">Twitter</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank">Facebook</a>';
        $content .= '<a class="crunchify-link crunchify-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" target="_blank">Pin It</a>';
        $content .= '</div>';

        echo $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does show up with your code? Give us a little help here.

Comment: `$crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', 'New -' . get_the_title());`

Comment: how do I add text like this " brave & co" , it shows up like Brave , the & c0 doesn't show up.
$crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', 'Brave & co -' . get_the_title());

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use concatenation in order to add some text before your title.

```php
$title = 'Title';
$newTitle = 'I am a '. $title;

echo $newTitle; // I am a Title
```